# How to create custom annotation with range validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I need to check the inventory, and if it is below a minimum value, error, or if it is above a maximum value, error.  I have tried using "@range", "@min", and I don't think I can use those, so I coded a custom annotation, but I am getting the same error messages.  I believe it is because I am setting the attribute value to a variable, but I'm unsure.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Annotation:

```
package com.example.demo.validators;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Constraint(validatedBy = {invrangeValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface invrange {
    String message() default "Inventory must be between Minimum and Maximum values!";
    Class<?> [] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};

    int maxInv();
    int minInv();
}
```

Validator:

```
package com.example.demo.validators;

import org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class invrangeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<invrange, Integer> {
    private int maxInv;
    private int minInv;

    @Override
    public void initialize(invrange constraintAnnotation) {
        maxInv = constraintAnnotation.maxInv();
        minInv = constraintAnnotation.minInv();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer integer, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (integer > maxInv && integer < minInv) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import com.example.demo.validators.ValidDeletePart;
import com.example.demo.validators.invrange;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 *
 *
 *
 */
@Entity
@ValidDeletePart
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="part_type",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="Parts")
public abstract class Part implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    String name;
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Price value must be positive")
    double price;

    int inv;
    int maxInv;
    int minInv;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="product_part", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="part_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    Set<Product> products= new HashSet<>();

    public Part() {
    }

    public Part(String name, double price, int inv, int maxInv, int minInv) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.inv = inv;
        this.maxInv = maxInv;
        this.minInv = minInv;
    }

    public Part(long id, String name, double price, int inv, int maxInv, int minInv) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.inv = inv;
        this.maxInv = maxInv;
        this.minInv = minInv;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getInv() {
        return inv;
    }

    @invrange(maxInv = minInv, minInv = maxInv)
    public void setInv(int inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
    }

    public int getMaxInv() {return maxInv;}
    public void setMaxInv(int maxInv){this.maxInv = maxInv;}
    public int getMinInv(){return minInv;}
    public void setMinInv(int minInv){this.minInv = minInv;}
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Part part = (Part) o;

        return id == part.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    }
}
```

Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Part Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Outsourced Part Detail</h1>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/showFormAddOutPart}" th:object="${outsourcedpart}" method="POST"}>

<!-- Add hidden form field to handle update -->
    <p><input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/></p>

    <p>Name:</p>
<p><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"/></p>

<p>Price:</p>
<p><input type="text" th:field="*{price}" placeholder= "Price" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"/></p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('price')}" th:errors="*{price}">Price Error</p>

    <p>Inventory:</p>
<p><input type="text" th:field="*{inv}" placeholder="Inventory" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"/></p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('inv')}" th:errors="*{inv}">Inventory Error</p>

    <p>Maximum Inventory:</p>
    <p><input type="text" th:field="*{maxInv}" placeholder="Max Inv" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"></p>

    <p>Minimum Inventory:</p>
    <p><input type="text" th:field="*{minInv}" placeholder="Min Inv" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"></p>

    <p>Company Name:</p>
    <p><input type="text" th:field="*{companyName}" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"/></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/">Link
    to Main Screen</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using "@range", "@min", and I don't think I can use those, so I coded a custom annotation

Comment: I forgot, here is my error message: Attribute value must be constant

Comment: Values for annotation parameters must be constant expressions, literals, enums, class literals, or array literals, but not variables.

Comment: What do you think `@invrange(maxInv = minInv, minInv = maxInv)` would accomplish? The values of those params __must__ be resolved to constants __by the compiler__. That's fundamental to annotations.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: `nteger > maxInv && integer < minInv` -- You return false if that condition evaluates to true, indicating you're trying to test if the value is outside the range, yet unless the min value is _greater than_ the max value, which I assume is an invalid scenario, then that condition can never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `integer > maxInv && integer < minInv` with `integer > maxInv || integer < minInv`